# Is there any difference between 'agree to something' and 'accept something'?

Tags: word-meaning

In a roundabout way I used to say:

> I agree to your proposal, but I don't accept it.

In Korean, I used to say this  when I was unwilling to do something and therefore wanted to decline it.

In Korea, the meaning of 'agree' is not equal to that of 'accept'. So, above expression is reasonable expression, if you say it at least in Korean.

By the way it seems somewhat illogical to say that in English.
I looked up the world 'agree' in Collins Cobuild dictionary this morning and found a explanation as follows:

> If you agree to do something, you say that you will do it. If you **agree** to a proposal, you **accept** it.

I wonder what difference is in using 'agree' and 'accept' at the same situation and whether the following expression is right:

> I agree to your proposal, but I don't accept it.

Comment: Please consult a good dictionary and select the defintions for **accept** and **agree** that  correspond best to these korean words, then edit your answer to add the definitions.Here is an example of a good dictionary. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agree

Comment: I can't think of any circumstances where it would make sense to say *I agree to your proposal, but I don't accept it.* If we reverse the terms and change the context slightly, you could certainly say *I accept your orders, but I don't agree with them*. That's to say, you can (unwillingly, reluctantly) accept and go along with a decision if you're being forced to, even though *in principle* you don't agree with the decision. But not the other way around.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should write an answer.

Comment: @user3169: I don't know Korean, and I don't understand why OP seems to have effectively "reversed" the relevant distinction between ***agree*** and ***accept*** after taking into account how the corresponding terms are used in Korean. Perhaps the problem lies in using a "translation" dictionary, rather than a "definitions" dictionary such as might be used by a native speaker. The point I made in my comment is trivial from the perspective of any native speaker, so anyone else could provide that information. But we could help OP more if we understood *why* he got things wrong in the first place.

Comment: @JavaLatte Thank you for your advise. I will use the Oxford dictionary next time, When I need look up something

Comment: @FumbleFingers ah! I also felt somewhat unreasonable the example in Collins Cobuild Dictionaly."If you agree to the proposal, you accept it", I thought that it would not make sense without  'auxiliary' in the subjective clause. So I asked help to find their difference taking own example by using same pattern in Collins dictionary. Thanks a lot! and thanks one more. I get to know an unknown word from your nickname. I can not think you have fumble fingers.

Comment: @doubleUFO: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_South_Korea) tells me that in *traditional* Korean society, women were taught the virtues of subordination and endurance to prepare for their future roles as wife and mother (same as most countries - if not today, many were certainly like that in the past). So I can imagine a "traditionally-minded" Korean wife saying to her English-speaking friend *My husband says I should always vote the way he does. I do not **agree** with his position, but I **accept** it.* (i.e. - I will reluctantly comply and do what he says).

Comment: ...can you say the same thing in Korean? Does Korean have two distinct verbs corresponding to ***agree*** and ***accept*** in the above?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  In that situation she can say so. But she continues to say "He oppresses my own political liberty every 4 years. If you keep it from others even your lover. Do not marry and live alone. Marriage is mad thing." then her friend say "I agree with what you say, but I don't accept it". This mean she want to marry.

Comment: @doubleUFO: In *that* case, you're simply setting up a context that allows an inherently contradictory statement to be made. What the friend actually means is she agrees with the ***assessment*** (being married is bad), but doesn't agree with the implied ***response*** (don't get married). Which is perfectly common in English (and in Korean, I'm sure), but it doesn't change the meanings of ***agree*** and ***accept***. What's happening is a kind of "play on words" where the ***subject*** of the two verbs isn't really the same thing (but the speaker wishes to blur that distinction).

Comment: (Either that or some even more convoluted distinction between what's being agreed to and what's not accepted. For example, I agree with you about marriage being bad, because I feel oppressed by *my* husband. But I don't accept that we should just put up with this. We should do whatever we can to *change* how they treat us.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank very much for your kind explanation! I understand it in case of 'play on words' having different objective. To summarize this I have one more question. If something is the same objective, 'agreeing something' might be followed by 'accepting something' but can not followed 'not accepting something'? That 'not accepting something' follows 'agree something' does not make sense? Thank in advance! ;-)

Comment: The essential difference is if you *agree with* some statement / description, that means you think it's *true*. If you *accept* [an instruction to do something, for example], that means you are prepared (perhaps *unwillingly*) to abide by the implications of it. So you could agree to accept an apology, for example (but you might *not* agree to accept it). Or you can accept an instruction from your boss (because he has the power to *force* you) even if you don't agree with him that whatever he wants you to do is a good idea.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank very very much! (ah It's sad for me to thank you only adding one more 'very'). I get to understand well. Have nice everydays! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context in which you are saying this, it would perhaps be better to say something like, "I agree to implement your proposal, but I'm not sure I accept its validity."

The key thing here is, that you are *agreeing* to do (implement) the task described in the proposal, but not *accepting* its merits or value. This is an important distinction, because it allows you to politely raise concerns (hence saying, "I'm not sure") about a task, without refusing to actually do it.

You could also swap out 'validity' for 'utility' if you wanted to suggest that the activity isn't particularly useful or productive.

Answer (score 1):

> I agree to your proposal, but I don't accept it.

is contradictory (at least, at first sight) because *agree **to*** generally means that you accept something. Some discussion on the matter can be found on ELU:
 [“Agree on” vs. “agree with” vs. “agree to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73696/agree-on-vs-agree-with-vs-agree-to).
In this case, you are accepting the terms of the proposal, and so you are essentially saying

> I accept your proposal, but I don't accept it.

(Contradiction.)

In other words, the preposition next to *agree* can change the meaning. It is possible you mean to say that you *agree **with*** the proposal. This means you accepts the points of the proposal, but for some unspecified reason, you cannot accept it (approve it, implement it, etc).

> I agree **with** your proposal, but I cannot accept it because it violates company policy.

for example.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive explanation. especially the last example!

Comment: One could say I can't agree with your proposal because it would violate the company policy.